# Database Reference Error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my iOS project, I am using Firebase to create a real time database.  I have already [imported it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFg9s.png) in the AppDelegate.swift.

[image: imported it]

When trying to reference my database within the app, an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pFgX.png) appears.

[image: error]

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Here is the code:

```
import UIKit 

import Firebase


class TableViewController: UITableViewController  {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        post()

        }

    func post(){


        let title = "Title"
        let message = "Message"

        let post : [String : AnyObject] = ["title" : title as AnyObject,
                                           "message" : message as AnyObject]

        let databaseRef = FirebaseApp.database().reference()

        databaseRef.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: I second your compiler.  I don't know what FirebaseApp is.  I don't know your Swift version, either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first configure firebase, example:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

then you can reference to the database:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
```

[FirebaseApp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) does not contain a method called `database()`

Comment: After configuring firebase in the AppDelegate.swift, I changed FirebaseApp to Database in my reference, and and error occurs that says 'Database' is an unresolved identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If your Firebase/Database version is 4.9.0, the following should give you a good start.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // MARK: - Instance variables
    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //getting a reference to the node artists
        databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does something change on 5.0.0+ version of database? I am receiving a Fetcher class error on databaseRef = Database.database().reference() and I can't understand what might be the issue, since nothing changed from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'Firebase/Database' to your pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

Then update the pods

```
pod install
```

Into your code be sure to import firebase

```
import Firebase
```

And use it as

```
 FirebaseApp.configure()
 var ref: DatabaseReference!
 ref = Database.database().reference()
 ref.setValue("Testing")
```

More info on [Firebase help](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start)